# Переключение между вкладками в структуре

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

На сайте есть что-то вроде таблицы, у которой есть свои вкладки 111, 222, 333. У каждой вкладки есть свои пункты, как мне переключаться между этими вкладками без перезагрузки страницы?

```
<div class="trading__market">
                                <div class="tradigng__market-search">
                                    <div class="trading__h">Markets</div>
                                    <input type="text">
                                </div>
                                <div class="trading__buy-title">
                                    <nav>
                                        <div class="trading__nav-active"><span>111</span></div> <!-- active class -->
                                        <div><span>222</span></div>
                                        <div><span>333</span></div>
                                    </nav>

                                <div class="trading__market-table-title">
                                    <div>Coin</div>
                                    <div>Price</div>
                                    <div class="trading__market-vol">Volume</div>
                                    <div>Change</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="trading__market-table">
                                    <div class="trading__market-table-row">
                                        <div class="trading__market-table-wrap">
                                            <div class="trading__market-table-circle trading__market-table-circle--green"></div> <!-- green -->
                                            <div class="trading__market-table-coin">ETH</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="trading__market-table-price">0.057353523<span></span></div>
                                        <div class="trading__market-table-volume">124.65</div>
                                        <div class="trading__market-table-change trading__market-table-change--red">-1.5%</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="trading__market-table-row">
                                        <div class="trading__market-table-wrap">
                                            <div class="trading__market-table-circle trading__market-table-circle--green"></div>
                                            <div class="trading__market-table-coin">USD</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="trading__market-table-price">8 170<span></span></div>
                                        <div class="trading__market-table-volume">1699</div>
                                        <div class="trading__market-table-change trading__market-table-change--red">-1.7%</div> <!-- red -->
                                    </div>
```

Comment: Ну это уже слишком.... https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Comment: Самый первый результат в гугле